# how to greensock tween a backbone model property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tween, backbone-model, gsap

```
var user = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
      timeLeft: 0
   }
});
```

Backbone model attributes are changed with: `user.set('timeLeft', 100)`

I need to tween this attribute with greensock. How can i tween a backbone model attribute?

Comment: I don't think this should be in the model but in the view instead. Care to elaborate?

Comment: my model is bound to html attributes via backbone views, so i change model to update dom.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. Anyways, I have an idea which I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Personally I don't see a problem with this property being in a model, but I can't imagine why you would tween it with greensock unless you wanted to apply easing to it. Is it not just a straight countdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I personally think that your mixing view logic into your model (that's a nono), you could listen to a `change` event on your `timeLeft` attribute.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        timeLeft: 0
    },
    initialize: {
        this.on("change:timeleft", this.timeLeftChanged);
    },
    timeLeftChanged: function(model, value, options) {
        // your rendering/tween logic
    }
});
```

Please keep in mind that this is untested and out of the top of my head, so it could be not working. ;-)